# How to calculate running balance in SQL

Tags: sql, derby, cumulative-sum

I am using embedded derby database and I want to add running balance column by calculating debit and credit amounts so please tell me solution code and image are also available below

(as you can see in image balance total is not accurate)

```
SELECT 
V_DATE,FLAG,V_NUM,V_NARATION,
sum(VDTL.DR_AMOUNT) AS DEBIT,
sum(VDTL.CR_AMOUNT) AS CRIDIT,
sum(dr_amount)-sum(cr_amount) as total
FROM VOUCHARDETAIL AS VDTL
INNER JOIN VOUCHARMASTER AS VMST
ON VDTL.DTL_NUM =VMST.MST_NUM
WHERE (V_DATE BETWEEN '12-03-2017' AND '14-03-2017') AND (FLAG='IV' OR FLAG='BR'
OR FLAG='CP' OR FLAG='CR' OR FLAG='JV' OR FLAG='BP') AND (AC_CODE=60030002) 
GROUP BY
V_DATE,FLAG,V_NUM,V_NARATION
ORDER BY
V_DATE
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any table schema/relation? And any sample or expect result?

Answer (score 1):

```
Begin Tran

--------------------------------------------------------------------
--Sample Data for Running Total 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE RunTotalTestData (
   id    int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
   value int not null
);

INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (9);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (12);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (13);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (16);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (22);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (42);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (57);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (58);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (59);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (60);


SELECT a.id, a.value, (SELECT SUM(b.value)
                       FROM RunTotalTestData b
                       WHERE b.id <= a.id) Runningtotal
FROM   RunTotalTestData a
ORDER BY a.id;

RollBack Tran
```

Comment: thanks for replay but please tell me solution through y code

Comment: DEAR BRO MY SAMPLE CODE ALREADY MENTION IN MY QUESTION